# Shifting row values by lag value in another column

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have a rather large dataset and I am interested in "marching" values forward through time based on values from another column. For example, if I have a `Value = 3` at `Time = 0` and a `DesiredShift = 2`, I want the 3 to shift down two rows to be at `Time = 2`. Here is a reproducible example.

## Build reproducible fake data

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
rowsPerID <- 8
dat <- CJ(1:2, 1:rowsPerID)
setnames(dat, c("ID","Time"))
dat[, Value := rpois(.N, 4)]
dat[, Shift := sample(0:2, size=.N, replace=TRUE)]
```

## Fake Data

```
#     ID Time Value Shift
#  1:  1    1     3     2
#  2:  1    2     3     2
#  3:  1    3     4     1
#  4:  1    4     7     2
#  5:  1    5     2     2
#  6:  1    6     7     0
#  7:  1    7     7     1
#  8:  1    8     5     0
#  9:  2    1     5     0
# 10:  2    2     1     1
# 11:  2    3     2     0
# 12:  2    4     2     1
# 13:  2    5     5     2
# 14:  2    6     3     1
# 15:  2    7     5     1
# 16:  2    8     4     1
```

I want each `Value` to shift forward according the the `Shift` column. So the
`DesiredOutput` column for row 3 will be equal to 3 since the value at `Time=1` is 
`Value = 3` and `Shift = 2`.

Row 4 shows 3+4=7 since 3 shifts down 2 and 4 shifts down 1.

I would like to be able to do this by ID group and hopefully take advantage
of `data.table` since speed is of interest for this problem.

## Desired Result

```
#     ID Time Value Shift DesiredOutput
#  1:  1    1     3     2       NA
#  2:  1    2     3     2       NA
#  3:  1    3     4     1       3
#  4:  1    4     7     2       3+4 = 7
#  5:  1    5     2     2       NA
#  6:  1    6     7     0       7+7 = 14
#  7:  1    7     7     1       2
#  8:  1    8     5     0       7+5 = 12
#  9:  2    1     5     0       5
# 10:  2    2     1     1       NA
# 11:  2    3     2     0       1+2 = 3
# 12:  2    4     2     1       NA
# 13:  2    5     5     2       2
# 14:  2    6     3     1       NA
# 15:  2    7     5     1       3+5=8
# 16:  2    8     4     1       5
```

I was hoping to get this working using the `data.table::shift` function, but I am unsure how to make this work using multiple lag parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
dat[, TargetIndex:= .I + Shift]

toMerge = dat[, list(Out = sum(Value)), by='TargetIndex']

dat[, TargetIndex:= .I]

# dat = merge(dat, toMerge, by='TargetIndex', all=TRUE)
dat[toMerge, on='TargetIndex', DesiredOutput:= i.Out]

> dat
#     ID Time Value Shift TargetIndex DesiredOutput
#  1:  1    1     3     2           1            NA
#  2:  1    2     3     2           2            NA
#  3:  1    3     4     1           3             3
#  4:  1    4     7     2           4             7
#  5:  1    5     2     2           5            NA
#  6:  1    6     7     0           6            14
#  7:  1    7     7     1           7             2
#  8:  1    8     5     0           8            12
#  9:  2    1     5     0           9             5
# 10:  2    2     1     1          10            NA
# 11:  2    3     2     0          11             3
# 12:  2    4     2     1          12            NA
# 13:  2    5     5     2          13             2
# 14:  2    6     3     1          14            NA
# 15:  2    7     5     1          15             8
# 16:  2    8     4     1          16             5
```

Comment: Yeah, I was posting almost the same thing, though your last step is doing unnecessary copy. You could probably do `dat[toMerge, on = "TargetIndex", DesiredOutput := i.Out]` instead.

Comment: I guess row indexing might be cheaper than a merge: `m = dat[, .(rid = Shift + .I, v = Value) ][ rid <= .N, sum(v), by=rid ]; dat[m$rid, x := m$V1 ]` I'm not sure this gives expected results, though. Also, fyi, you can dynamically define a `by` column, like `by=.(TargetIndex + Shift)`, I think.

Comment: This `toMerge = dat[, list(Out = sum(Value)), by='TargetIndex']` part is pretty costly for big datasets, but I am unsure of a way to avoid it.

Comment: @Mike.Gahan In general, I doubt that you can. Fwiw, sum by group is optimized already by this answer. See `?GForce`